# Conditional MySQL INSERT if record number is set at specific number

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm creating a simple session based app in PHP/MySQL. I'm storing a session for each user connected to app in mysql table with their associated session_id. What I want to do is stop recording once a certain specified number of records are inserted in table. Is it possible in MySQL?

Below is a sample query that I thought would work, but it doesn't.

```
$dbSessionQ = "INSERT INTO `connSessions` (`sessID`, `expiry`) VALUES ('" . session_id() . "', '3600')";
$dbSessionQ .= "WHERE (SELECT COUNT(`sessID`) FROM `connSessions` < 5001) LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: You can query db using `SELECT COUNT(sessID) FROM connSessions` and *IF* result is less than your max allowed, run your INSERT query

Comment: Application logic should not be inside your query.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Just wanted to know if it is possible using single query.

Comment: @YoGi, it is possible with `insert into .. select ..` syntax, though I would not advise to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think INSERT has a WHERE clause.
To start with, you can first query for the count and then do the insert. (Split the SELECT and the INSERT statements). Once you've figured that out, use a simple transaction to eliminate race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) for this. Something like

```
INSERT INTO `connSessions` (`sessID`, `expiry`)
SELECT '" . session_id() . "', '3600' FROM `connSessions`
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(`sessID`) FROM `connSessions`) < 5001
```

But since you are not selecting something from connSessions I do not really see what you want to do here.